# Hibernate @OneToOne Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have set up a relationship between 2 tables using hibernate. The parent record doesn't always have a child record that goes along with it, so when I query the table to bring back the result set, I get a "collection is not associated with any session" exception.

This exception does not occur when the result set consists of only records with children or only records without children; it only occurs when the result set is mixed.

Is there an annotation I can use so that when the parent record doesn't have an associated child record the query doesn't throw the exception? I tried using @NotFound to ignore the lack of a child record, but it did not work. I still get the same exception.

I have searched the internet for a solution to this problem, but it seems like Hibernate wasn't set up to handle this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the child records too:

```
select p
from Parent p
left join fetch p.child
```

where **child** is the @OneToOne association from Parent to Child.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us your classes. I don't understand how can you have collection in OneToOne relationship. Maybe try to set optional = true on your property.